# Ignoring column on updating with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have this EF database-first EDMX file that I created it with a local copy of the database to which It will run, and what It'll basically do is a mass update on the database. Now, we have various databases, all with the same layout EXCEPT that some have IN AL TABLES an extra column. That extra column is none of my importance right now, so I would like a way to tell EF to simply skip that column if it's not there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your EDMX model doesn't know about this extra column (i.e. there is no mapping of an entity property to the column), then you can run your model against databases with the extra column without problem. Entity Framwork won't even take those column into account when converting entity queries into SQL.

Comment: That worked for me. Re-generated the model with a database that didn't had the column. Thanks.